# After I said bad things about him, he got angry(,) and I got scared from looking at his angry face. - meaning differences?

Tags: meaning, punctuation

**Example 1**

> After I said bad things about him, he got angry and I got scared from looking at his angry face.

**Example 2**

> After I said bad things about him, he got angry, and I got scared from looking at his angry face.

Which one is correct?

---

For me, Example 1 sounds wierd because the cause-and-effect is in one unit even though logically me getting angry is indeed after I said something.
In Example 2, me getting scared is a standablone sentence, which sounds better to my ears.

Comment: It's perfectly normal to use "and" to join two clauses separated in time, eg "He caught pneumonia and died".

Comment: The sentence (1) **sounds** bad? Can you really hear the lack of a written comma?

Comment: I got scared from looking at his angry face. is not right. I was scared **by** his angry face. The got scared is a bit much.

Answer (score -1):

In OP's *exact* example the presence or absence of the comma (*pause*, in speech) can't make any difference to the meaning, because there ***is*** only one possible meaning in terms of causes and effects. But consider something just *slightly* different, such as...

> *After I insulted them, he got angry[**,**] and she appealed for calm*

...it ***is*** possible for the comma to affect the parsing. With no comma we're more likely to tie both "outcomes" together as reactions to me insulting them. *With* the comma, it's easier to understand her appeal for calm as a reaction to him getting angry.

Note that these are just *possible* interpretations. The presence or absence of the comma/pause doesn't *unambiguously* determine which parsing applies.